# Set the publicURL of a static File node, or create a duplicate file node in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, static-site

I am using Gatsby JS to create a static site. The website is being dynamically built from text files using the `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin. My config for it is as follows:

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `Wrappers`,
        path: `${__dirname}/ToolWrappers`,
      },
    },
```

My requirement is to have stable, systematic URLs for some of my static source files. By default they are being assigned a `publicURL` such as `/static/e97a5c9f35ab32ea270703045bec732d/bwa_aln.cwl`, but I need it to be accessible at `/packages/bwa/0.7.17/bwa_aln/bwa_aln.cwl`. In other words I need to customize the `publicURL` of these `File` nodes.

My first attempt was to create a new React page at `/packages/bwa/0.7.17/bwa_aln/bwa_aln.cwl` which redirects to the static URL, but this is not sufficient because I need this to work as an API that returns raw text data, not HTML.

Secondly, I have tried modifying the URLs of the `File` nodes using this code in `gatsby-node.js`:

```js
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions }) => {
  const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === 'File'){
    const fields = filenameAttributes(node.relativePath)
    createNodeField({node, name: 'publicURL', value: fields.wrapperUrl})
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to actually "stick". The `publicURL` remains unchanged when I query it in the graphQL browser, and the URL of the actual text files is unaffected.

How can I either modify the `publicURL` of these files, or else make duplicates of these files with a custom URL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a folder structure like `/static/packages/bwa/0.7.17/bwa_aln/{fileName.extension}`?

Gatsby by default, when builds the site, will clone the static folder's internal structure to the `/public` folder, making the assets available at `localhost:8000/packages/bwa/0.7.17/bwa_aln/{fileName.extension}` (changing `{fileName.extension}` for the asset name).

> Note that my source text files are not located in the static folder.
> They are located in a different place (`${__dirname}/ToolWrappers`) and
> are being imported into Gatsby using `gatsby-source-filesystem`. I don't
> have control over this folder structure anyway. So this won't help
> here.

In that case, this plugin may be helpful: [`gatsby-plugin-copy-files`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-copy-files/):

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-copy-files',
    options: {
        source: `${__dirname}/ToolWrappers`,
        destination: '/static'
    }
},
```

Comment: Note that my source text files are *not* located in the static folder. They are located in a different place (`${__dirname}/ToolWrappers`) and are being imported into Gatsby using `gatsby-source-filesystem`. I don't have control over this folder structure anyway. So this won't help here.

Comment: Maybe this plugin helps you: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-copy-files/